# is it possible to set and retrieve flashdata in sessions_start() hook

Tags: add-on-development

I'm attempting to set flashdata in the sessions_start() hook and retrieve it on the next page load. It does not seem to work although I am able to set_flashdata and then var_dump the session object and see the new flashdata variable, just not able to see it or retrieve it on the next page load.

Does anyone know if you can reliably set and retrieve flashdata within the sessions_start() hook?

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes - `set_flashdata()` only works in conjunction with `ee()->functions->redirect()`, as per [the docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#flash-data-for-redirects):

> NOTE: Due to internal limitations this will only work in combination with the redirect method of the Functions class.

So it will not work in `sesions_start()` or `sessions_end()`.